# Match words not beginning with &

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that can match words (case insensitive) that do not begin with & character

For example search string **Foo**

Then match would be something like:

- **foo**
- **Foo**
- **Foo**bar
- Bar **Foo**
- Bar**Foo**
- Bar **Foo**bar
- $**Foo**bar
- $**Foo**$
- **Foo** $**Foo** %**Foo** &Foo **Foo**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind assertion like below,

```
(?i)(?<!&)foo
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?i)` Case insensitive modifier.
- `(?<!&)` Negative lookbehind asserts that the match would be preceded by any but not of `&` character.
- `foo` matches the string foo

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zU7dA5/13)

For js,

```
/(?:[^&]|^)(foo)/igm
```

Get the string you want from group index 1.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zU7dA5/14)

```
> var s = "Foo $Foo %Foo &Foo Foo";
undefined
> var re = /(?:[^&]|^)(foo)/igm;
undefined
> var m;
undefined
> while ((m = re.exec(s)) != null) {
... console.log(m[1]);
... }
Foo
Foo
Foo
Foo
```

Through `string.replace` method.

```
> var s = "Foo $Foo %Foo &Foo Foo";
undefined
> s.replace(/([^&]|^)(foo)/igm, "$1bar")
'bar $bar %bar &Foo bar'
```

Comment: javascript won't support lookbehinds. Which lang are you running?

Comment: I am using JavaScript :)

Comment: Thank you, it kinda works but it matches a space in the beginning

Comment: yep, see the captures at the right side in the above demo link. You need to print group index 1 instead of index 0.

Comment: I'm using `string.replace()`

Comment: Whats your expected output for this `Foo $Foo %Foo &Foo Foo`?

Comment: Actually I'm using AngularJS, my methods looks like the following: `$scope.highlight = function(text, search) {
  if (!search) {
   return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
  }
  
  return $sce.trustAsHtml(text.replace(new RegExp('([^&]|^)(' + search + ')', 'igm'), '<span class="highlight">$1</span>'));
 };`

Comment: use `"` as delimiter instead of `'` while using the regex in RegEx constructor like `RegExp("`

Comment: Thank you, but the problem persists. My regex is now this: `"(" + search + ")(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*</)", 'ig')` but it still matches the `c` in Mapping fr&aa**c**ute;

Comment: Please fix your answer to be only for Javascript, as it may confuse other readers as to why the accepted answer at the top is not compatible with Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

This should be Javascript-friendly for a pattern. It uses non-capture groups and makes sure that `foo` is not preceeded by an ampersand (&)

```
(?:[^&])[fF][oO][oO]
```

Non-foo characters that are NOT ampersand will show up in the match, but not in the results/capture.

EDIT: You may use the 'i' flag in your javascript regex syntax to invoke the case-insensitive mode modiefer. Then the pattern would just be `(?:[^&])foo`